# Lp eigenfuntion bounds for the hermite operator on domain (or manifolds) with boundary

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

Let's define the harmonic oscillator $H = -\Delta+x^2$ in a domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^d$. Thus,
we consider the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem
$$ (H - \lambda^2)u (x) = 0, \ x \in \Omega ;  \  \text{ and } \ u(x) = 0 \ x \in \partial \Omega.$$
Denote the spectral projection to the eigenvalue $ k = \lambda^2 $ by $P_k$.

My question is: Are there any $L^p$ bounds results for eigenfunctions of the Hermite operator $H$ that have the form
$$ \| P_k u \|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq k^{\rho(p)} \| u\|_{L^2(\Omega)},$$ where $p$ would be in $[2, 2d/(d-2)]$ and the exponent $\rho$ as function of $1/p$.

Note that in the case of $\Omega = \mathbb R^d$ there are many results, Karadzhov 1994, Thangavelu 1998, Koch and Tataru 2004.

Comment: The nonnegative integers are the eigenvalues on the whole space but not in $\Omega$.

Comment: Interesting, but I did not mention that they are integers.

Comment: You denoted by $P_k$ the spectral projection relative to the eigenvalue $k=\lambda^2$...I am referring to that.

Comment: Yes, my apologies if that appears a bit confusing.

Comment: Please correct, then. Do you mean that $P_k$ is the spectral projection relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$?

Comment: Where you wrote $−∆+x^2$, the spacing surrounding the $\text{“}{+}\text{”}$ sign was not there, and I edited it to say $-\Delta+x^2.$ Sometimes MathJax is not as good as LaTeX when you use code like `∆` instead of `\Delta`.

Comment: On bounded domains, this question is entirely related to the asymptotics of $\lambda_k$ as a function of $k$: you have that $\int |\nabla P_k u|^2 \leq \lambda_k \int u^2$ by definition, and then you apply Sobolev embeddings (unless you are interested in the sharp constant term by term). As I understand it, the heuristic is usually that if your potential is nice, the asymptotics of $\lambda_k$ are the same as without the potential. The problem on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or unbounded domains), on the other hand, seems quite different and more challenging.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the comment. Yes, I'm only interested in the sharp case.  I think on $\mathbb R^d$ the problem was done by (Koch and Tataru 2004, for example). I'm mostly interested in the share case for the boundary problem.